# fluentd JSON log field not being parsed

Tags: docker, fluentd

I'm following the `fluentd` tutorial at https://docs.fluentd.org/container-deployment/docker-logging-driver

But I'm unable to make the JSON parser work.

I'm running fluentd as follow:

```
# ./demo.conf
<source>
  @type forward
  port 24224
  bind 0.0.0.0
</source>

<match *>
  @type stdout
</match>

<filter docker.**>
  @type parser
  key_name log
  reserve_data true
  <parse>
    @type json # apache2, nginx, etc...
  </parse>
</filter>
```

```
docker run -it -p 24224:24224 -v $(pwd)/demo.conf:/fluentd/etc/demo.conf -e FLUENTD_CONF=demo.conf fluent/fluentd:v1.3.2
```

and I'm using the following `docker run` command to mock a JSON log to `fluentd`

```
docker run --log-driver=fluentd ubuntu echo '{"test":"test"}'
```

```
Expected: 2020-06-23 13:52:31.000000000 +0000 e54806b99130: {"log":"{\"test\":\"test\"}","container_id":"e54806b9913010d5ecb79b305d227db9e706299ad94bd070be6042dce735ed3b","container_name":"/wizardly_kalam","source":"stdout","test":"test"}
Actual:   2020-06-23 13:52:31.000000000 +0000 e54806b99130: {"log":"{\"test\":\"test\"}","container_id":"e54806b9913010d5ecb79b305d227db9e706299ad94bd070be6042dce735ed3b","container_name":"/wizardly_kalam","source":"stdout"}
```

Acording to the [reserve_data](http://2020-06-23%2013:52:31.000000000%20+0000%20e54806b99130:%20%7B%22log%22:%22%7B%5C%22test%5C%22:%5C%22test%5C%22%7D%22,%22container_id%22:%22e54806b9913010d5ecb79b305d227db9e706299ad94bd070be6042dce735ed3b%22,%22container_name%22:%22/wizardly_kalam%22,%22source%22:%22stdout%22%7D) doc it suppose to work but I'm unable to understand what is the issue.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Maybe I'm missing something, but doesn't Fluentd respect the order of steps in the config? You print to stdout before parsing the fields. Try this:

```
# ./demo.conf
<source>
  @type forward
  port 24224
  bind 0.0.0.0
</source>

<filter docker.**>
  @type parser
  key_name log
  reserve_data true
  <parse>
    @type json # apache2, nginx, etc...
  </parse>
</filter>

<match *>
  @type stdout
</match>
```

Comment: My Bad, The Answer is correct. I just had an additional issue with the docker --log-opt tag as well.